# Android rotate animation between two activity?

Tags: android

How to put rotate animation between two activities.when is startactivity and next activity is start with rotate animation

Comment: did the below solution worked as you expected??

Comment: i changed the duration from "300" to "3000" just to check the actual animation clearly. as soon as i click the button to go from ActivityA to ActivityB, screen gets black, then slowly the ActivityA appears and then ActivityB appears

Comment: this is not working as i was expecting,,, Archie is ryt ,,this is how it is appearing,,,how can we show flip while going from one activity to another,,,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.41post.com/3368/programming/android-changing-the-animation-between-activities) on  how to add an animation when transistioning between two activities. However, instead of using a translate animation like in the article, you'll want to use a rotate animation. For more information on animations, checkout this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View).

Putting those two things together, here's what you need to do. First, where you make the call to start the new activity do this:

```
//Calls a new Activity  
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));  

//Set the transition -> method available from Android 2.0 and beyond  
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rotate_out,R.anim.rotate_in);
```

Then create the following two animations in your xml:

rotate_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />  
   <rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="90" android:pivotX="25%" />
</set>
```

rotate_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />  
   <rotate android:fromDegrees="90" android:toDegrees="0" android:pivotX="-25%" />
</set>
```

You can play with the fromDegrees, toDegrees, and pivotX values to get exactly what you'd like.

Comment: @Ankit : did u find solution for this?

Comment: yup i do with Rotate animation3D ...See in android api have demo

Comment: @ Samir Mangroliya: did the above solution worked as you expected??

Comment: this is a .@|#12dsa