# How to make a page flip like animation when changing between activities?

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I make a page flip like animation when moving from one activity to other? On some ios applications I saw this, but when I searched for android I could not find any tutorials or code snippets for this.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible . Please look at this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854262/614807).

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.41post.com/3368/programming/android-changing-the-animation-between-activities) on how to add an animation when transistioning between two activities. However, instead of using a translate animation like in the article, you'll want to use a rotate animation.

Comment: the animation after using the code you posted is, "screen blinks for some 0.25 secs and shows the called activity", it in no way looked like a rotation or flipping :(

Comment: i changed the duration from "300" to "3000" just to check the actual animation clearly. as soon as i click the button to go from ActivityA to ActivityB, screen gets black, then slowly the ActivityA appears and then ActivityB appears

Answer (score 0):

The flip animation for `Activity` doesn't exist on Android..sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here is demo code from sdk:

```
/**
 * <p>Example of using a custom animation when transitioning between activities.</p>
 */
public class Animation extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fade_animation);
        button.setOnClickListener(mFadeListener);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zoom_animation);
        button.setOnClickListener(mZoomListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener mFadeListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Request the next activity transition (here starting a new one).
            startActivity(new Intent(Animation.this, Controls1.class));
            // Supply a custom animation.  This one will just fade the new
            // activity on top.  Note that we need to also supply an animation
            // (here just doing nothing for the same amount of time) for the
            // old activity to prevent it from going away too soon.
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.hold);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener mZoomListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Request the next activity transition (here starting a new one).
            startActivity(new Intent(Animation.this, Controls1.class));
            // This is a more complicated animation, involving transformations
            // on both this (exit) and the new (enter) activity.  Note how for
            // the duration of the animation we force the exiting activity
            // to be Z-ordered on top (even though it really isn't) to achieve
            // the effect we want.
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
        }
    };
}
```

all code is at apidemo/app/ ,:)

Comment: can you please provide the link for apidemo/app/ which you were saying