# Rotation or Page Flip like animation in android, when moving from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-animation

I want a flip like animation when moving from one activity to another. Like this:

http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

I followed this solution posted on SOF:

[Android rotate animation between two activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853997/android-rotate-animation-between-two-activity#answers-header)

```
//Calls a new Activity  
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));  

//Set the transition -> method available from Android 2.0 and beyond  
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rotate_out,R.anim.rotate_in);
```

rotate_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />  
   <rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="90" android:pivotX="25%" />
</set>
```

rotate_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />  
   <rotate android:fromDegrees="90" android:toDegrees="0" android:pivotX="-25%" />
</set>
```

but the outcome is:

i changed the duration from "300" to "3000" just to check the actual animation clearly. as soon as i click the button to go from ActivityA to ActivityB, screen gets black, then slowly the ActivityA appears and then suddenly ActivityB appears

and i am using Android 2.3.3(API 10)

Can any one help me achieve what i wanted?

Answer (score 0):

if you have changed the duration from 300 to 3000 it will only slow down the animation. First make it 1500 which is fine to notice the animation. Second if you want page flip you can just change the degree of "from" and "to" check this code

in rotate_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1500" />  
<rotate android:fromDegrees="75" android:toDegrees="180" android:pivotX="-25%" />
</set>
```

in rotate_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1500" />  
<rotate android:fromDegrees="180" android:toDegrees="-75" android:pivotX="25%" />
</set>
```

I hope this is what you wanted, this code is to flip page from top left to bottom right.

Comment: Thanks for the code but that does not work well for me..! It just shows a black background, and the new activity is slightly tilted in the air while all the other part of the screen is black..! Its really laggy, on a well working Nexus 5..!